# dart/flutter: getting data array from C/C++ using ffi?

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, language-interoperability

[The official flutter tutorial on C/C++ interop through ffi](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop) only touches on calling a C++ function and getting a single return value.

### Goal

What if I have a data buffer created on C/C++ side, but want to deliver to dart/flutter-side to show?

### Problem

With @MilesBudnek 's tip, I'm testing Dart's FFI by trying to have safe memory deallocation from Dart to C/C++. The test reuses [the official struct sample](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop) .

I could get the Array as a dart `Pointer`, but it's unclear to me how to iterate the array as a collection easily.

### Code

I'm implementing a Dart-side C array binding like this:

In `struct.h`

```cpp
struct Array
{
    int* array;
    int len;
};
```

and a pair of simple allocation/deallocation test functions:

```cpp
struct Array* get_array();
int del_array(struct Array* arr);
```

Then on Dart side in `structs.dart`:

```dart
typedef get_array_func = Pointer<Array> Function();
typedef del_array_func = void Function(int arrAddress);

...

  final getArrayPointer = dylib.lookup<NativeFunction<get_array_func>>('get_array');
  final getArray = getArrayPointer.asFunction<get_array_func>();
  final arrayPointer = getArray();
  final array = arrayPointer.ref.array;
  print('array.array: $array');
```

This gives me the print out

```sh
array.array: Pointer<Int32>: address=0x7fb0a5900000
```

### Question

Can I convert the array pointer to a `List` easily? Something like:

```dart
final array = arrayPointer.ref.array.toList();
array.forEach(index, elem) => print("array[$idx]: $elem");
```

### ======

## Old Question (you can skip this)

### Problem

It's unclear to me how to retrieve this kind of vector data from C/C++ by dart/flutter.

### Possible solutions

More importantly, how to push data from C++ side from various threads?
If there is no builtin support, off the top of my head I'd need to implement some communication schemes.

#### Option #1: Networking

I could do network through TCP sockets. But I'm reluctant to go there if there are easier solutions.

#### Option #2: file I/O

Write data to file with C/C++, and let dart/flutter poll on the file and stream data over. This is not realtime friendly.

So, are there better options?

Comment: I'm not familiar with dart/flutter, but it looks like it supports [pointers](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.8.0-dev.17.0/dart-ffi/dart-ffi-library.html).  So you would return a pointer to the first element of an array allocated by your C++ code, use the data in dart, then pass that pointer back to another function in your C++ code to release the memory.  For example, see their [structs example](https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/tree/master/ffi/structs) (though they never free the memory allocated by `malloc` in that example).

Comment: @MilesBudnek I updated the question and would you please take a look? Thanks for the previous tip.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/ffi/issues/22), the API [asTypedList](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-ffi/Uint8Pointer/asTypedList.html) is the way to go.

Here is the code that works for me

```dart
  final getArrayPointer = dylib.lookup<NativeFunction<get_array_func>>('get_array');
  final getArray = getArrayPointer.asFunction<get_array_func>();
  final arrayPointer = getArray();
  final arr = arrayPointer.ref.arr;
  print('array.array: $arr');
  final arrReal = arr.asTypedList(10);
  final arrType = arrReal.runtimeType;
  print('arrReal: $arrReal, $arrType');
  arrReal.forEach((elem) => print("array: $elem"));
```

This gives me:

```sh
array.array: Pointer<Int32>: address=0x7f9eebb02870
arrReal: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], Int32List
array: 0
array: 1
array: 2
array: 3
array: 4
array: 5
array: 6
array: 7
array: 8
array: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

`asTypedList` will only work with pointers that relate to `TypedData`.

there are other cases where, for example, you want to convert an `Pointer<UnsignedChar>` to a `Uint8List`, in this case you can:

- use an extension and then either cast the `Pointer<UnsignedChar` to a `Pointer<Uint8>` and then use `asTypedList`. In this case you have to make sure the pointer is not freed while the `Uint8List` is still referenced.

```
extension UnsignedCharPointerExtension on Pointer<UnsignedChar> {
  Uint8List? toUint8List(int length) {
    if (this == nullptr) {
      return null;
    }
    return cast<Uint8>().asTypedList(length);
  }
}
```

- use an extension and don't cast the pointer but copy it manually. In this case you can free the pointer after you get the `Uint8List`

```
extension UnsignedCharPointerExtension on Pointer<UnsignedChar> {
  Uint8List? toUint8List(int length) {
    if (this == nullptr) {
      return null;
    }
    final Uint8List list = Uint8List(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      list[i] = this[i];
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```